# Python how to train the naives bayes classier

Tags: python, classification

I need a classifier to classify the reviews to positive or negative. For each doc I had done the stopwords filtering and lemmatation and computed the tf-idf for each term and stored them into doc_bow as follow for each doc.

```
doc_bow.append((term,tfidf)).
```

Now, I wan to train the classifier, but I have no idea how to do. I found an example from http://streamhacker.com/2010/10/25/training-binary-text-classifiers-nltk-trainer/, but still I can't get it. How the td-idf will be used or affect the classifier?

Comment: You linked an article for `NLTK` / `NLTK-trainer` but didn't tag this question as such - do you have both of those currently?

Comment: Totally I got 100 doc, I had manually label the 50 doc reviews. Does this consider the training set?

Comment: your labelled dataset is your training set...

Comment: So, with the doc_bow and training set how to train the classifier?

Answer (score 0):

I know only little in this area, but I can share what i understand. please correct me if I am wrong. From what i see from the link, there is no reference to using tf-idf scores for classification. You should look at the [link](http://streamhacker.com/2010/05/10/text-classification-sentiment-analysis-naive-bayes-classifier/) to understand how to use the naive bayes classifier. In general, the code looks like that (I took this code segment from that link)

```
import nltk.classify.util
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews

def word_feats(words):
    return dict([(word, True) for word in words])

negids = movie_reviews.fileids('neg')
posids = movie_reviews.fileids('pos')

negfeats = [(word_feats(movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'neg') for f in negids]
posfeats = [(word_feats(movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'pos') for f in posids]

negcutoff = len(negfeats)*3/4
poscutoff = len(posfeats)*3/4

trainfeats = negfeats[:negcutoff] + posfeats[:poscutoff]
testfeats = negfeats[negcutoff:] + posfeats[poscutoff:]
print 'train on %d instances, test on %d instances' % (len(trainfeats), len(testfeats))

classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainfeats)
```

Each training instance is a tuple of a dictionary of features and the class label, so for instance, it could be `({"sucks":True, "bad":True, "boring":True}, "Negative")`

As for numeric attribute, I think one common approach can be binning them into categories e.g low/medium/high.

With regards to `TF-IDF` scores, I am not very certain. I think one approach is that they can be used for features selection, for example if your no. of features is too large you may take the top n words as features.

Comment: Yes I saw this code as well, but I don't quite understand how to plug it into my case. So, I have to understand how it works first, and what is the usage of each variable, said tf-idf, pos tagging all those. Thanks for your answer, so what I need to do now is basically from the training set I extract out 2 list on is under positive another is negative. AM I right is that what this 2 lines mean? negfeats = [(word_feats(movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'neg') for f in negids]
posfeats = [(word_feats(movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'pos') for f in posids]

Comment: I don't quite get understand the dict() and the cutoff mean why is mutiple 3/4

Comment: dict converts a tuple into a dictionary, cutoff here means u use 3/4 of the data u labelled as training set, and the remaining 1/4 as a test set to see how good your classifier is. This is generally the case. 3/4 is just a convenient amount. it could be 9/10 training, 1/10 test set, depending how large your labelled data is. Please consider accepting my answer if u find it useful. thanks!